# paypal gem multiple accounts ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, multiple-accounts

I'm using the paypal-sdk-merchant gem. So far I have set one merchant account with this command:

```
PayPal::SDK.configure(
        :mode      => "sandbox",
        :app_id    => "APP-sdfgjkl",
        :username  => "lprieto-facilitator_api1.hasu.cl",
        :password  => "Z7XGVDCHBJN",
        :signature => "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRlXDCFVGBHLBRTnmAzXxHddoa5e",
        :sandbox_email_address => "lprieto-facilitator_api1.hasu.cl")
```

and then create a payment with

```
api         = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new
```

This have work perfectly so far but now I have to change the paypal account according to the country the person is buying from. **If I'm constantly changing the PayPal::SDK.configure will there be any consistence problems??**

For example, if a person in Brasil access and the configuration is change. Then a person in Chile access and the configuration is change. After, the brasilian pays. Will it have the brasilian configuration or the chilean one?

**What would you recommend for having multiple Paypal accounts in a ruby on rails app?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK because this gem doesn't support rails 4 and will be deprecated.

As for your problem at hand: Seeing the API, you would indeed need to call `PayPal::SDK.configure()` for each different type of merchant/country. You can create a YML config file for this something like `config/paypal.yml`:

```
chile:
  mode: sandbox
  app_id: APP-123
  username: user1
  password: pass1
  signature: ABCDEF
  sandbox_email_address: test@example.com

brasil:
  mode: sandbox
  app_id: APP-456
  username: user2
  password: pass2
  signature: GHIJKL
  sandbox_email_address: test2@example.com
```

and use this in your app like:

```
@api_chile = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new(:chile)
@api_brasil = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new(:brasil)
```

Hope this helps!